# prisma query existing item for failed unique key constraint

Tags: prisma

I have a form where clients can register for contests. They submit their name and email address, and the registration gets stored in a table in the database which has a composite primary key of the contestId and the clientId.

If someone submits the form a second time (i.e., tries to register for the same contest a second time), Prisma throws a failed constraint error. That's fine, and even expected, but I'd like to return the existing entry, and am having a hard time constructing the query.

Schema:

```
model Client {
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  email         String          @unique
  first         String?
  last          String?
  registrations Registration[]
}

model Contest {
  id            Int             @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String          @unique
  registrations Registration[]
}

model Registration {
  contest       Contest         @relation(fields: [contestId], references: [id])
  contestId     Int
  contestant    Client          @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
  clientId      Int
  points        Int

  @@id  ([contestId, clientId])
}
```

Registration:

```
try {
  const registration = await prisma.registration.create({
    data: {
      points: 1,
      contest: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: {
            name: contest,
          },
          create: {
            name: contest,
          }
        }
      },
      contestant: {
        connectOrCreate: {
          where: {
            email: email,
          },
          create: {
            first: first,
            last: last,
            email: email,
          },
        },
      },
    }
  });

  return res.status(201).send({ ...registration});
}
```

For new registrants that works, but if the registration already exists, I end up in the `catch` block. I assume this is the right way to do this — as opposed to, say, querying for existence first, because that seems expensive given that it's likely to be very rare that someone accidentally tries to re-register — but if this isn't a best practice on how to handle things, I'm open to other suggestions.

In the `catch` block, I then need to find the existing entry, but neither of the two things I've tried have worked:

```
catch (error) {
  // entry already exists
  if ('P2002' === error.code) {
    const registration = await prisma.registration.findUnique({
      where: {
        contest: {
          is: {
            name: contest,
          },
        },
        contestant: {
          is: {
            email: email,
          },
        },
      },
    })
    return res.status(200).send(...registration);
  }
  return res.status(500).end(`Register for contest errorr: ${error.message}`);
}
```

complains `Argument where of type RegistrationWhereUniqueInput needs exactly one argument, but you provided contest and contestant.`

And

```
const registration = await prisma.registration.findUnique({
  where: {
    contestId_clientId: {
      contest: {
        is: {
          name: contest,
        },
      },
      contestant: {
        is: {
          email: email,
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

complains

```
Unknown arg `contest` in where.contestId_clientId.contest for type RegistrationContestIdClientIdCompoundUniqueInput. Did you mean `contestId`?
Unknown arg `contestant` in where.contestId_clientId.contestant for type RegistrationContestIdClientIdCompoundUniqueInput. Did you mean `contestId`?
Argument contestId for where.contestId_clientId.contestId is missing.
Argument clientId for where.contestId_clientId.clientId is missing.
```

I feel like this latter approach of using Prisma's auto-generated `contestId_clientId` is directionally right, but how do I construct the Prisma query to find it, starting from having the contest name and client email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding a unique record from the registration model, you can do a query something like this to find the Contest and Client details. The only valid argument for findUnique in the registration model would be: `contestId_clientId` and you can only pass contestId and clientId in them, other values are not allowed.

```js
  const registration = await prisma.client.findUnique({
    where: {
      email: 'email',
    },
    include: {
      registrations: {
        select: {
          contest: contest,
          points: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

Comment: This definitely got me there — had to remove the second argument to where, and manually list all the fields from registrations. If you want to slightly update the answer, I'll mark it as correct: `where: { email: email }` and `include: { registrations: { select: { contest: contest, points: true } } }`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting and accepting the answer.